# How do I tell my model about the sample size of input statistics?

Tags: neural-network, feature-selection

Let's say I am trying to predict whether a cat will be adopted, and I have found the ratio `purred_when_petted / total_times_petted` aka `p / n` to have predictive power. However, for some cats I have much more data than others. For example:

```
Cat A:
    p: 1
    n: 1

Cat B:
    p: 9
    n: 10
```

I would like my neural network to consider that there is more data for Cat B and possible consider that it is more likely to be adopted. How should I tell it about both the ratio and the sample size?

Here are some ideas I have so far:

1. Use ratio as input feature and don't worry about sample size
2. Use ratio and sample size as separate input features
3. Use $p$ and $n$ as separate input features, and let the NN do what it wants with them.
4. Use an average of the cat statistic and the average population statistic over all $M$ cats weighted by number of samples:
   $$
   x_i = \beta  * (\frac{p_i}{n_i}) + (1-\beta) * (\frac{1}{M}\sum_{j=1}^{M}\frac{p_j}{n_j})
   $$
   where $\beta \in [0,1]$ is an increasing function of sample size $n_i$.
5. Use a [Binomial proportion confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)

Is there a standard way to do this? I am most interested in neural networks but also open to advice relevant to any other type of model.

Note that I also have other categorical and numeric features such as `color` and `age` that also need to be fed in to my model.